# oozie Mapreduce not finish or stop to run new job

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, oozie, bigdata

I try to running Pig from Oozie 
When Oozie job create Pig job mapreduce not finish the first job to begin Pig job it run 6hour and still run

[image]

Pig script

```
 A = load '$INPUT' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray, age:int, safary:int);
store A into '$OUTPUT' USING PigStorage(',');
```

job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://master:9000
jobTracker=master:8032
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=/user/root/share/lib/lib_20170611141905
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/pig
```

workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="pig-wf">
    <start to="pig-node"/>
    <action name="pig-node">
        <pig>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/pig_out"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>id.pig</script>
            <param>INPUT=/testHive.txt</param>
            <param>OUTPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/pig_out</param>
        </pig>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Pig failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

i don't see any error on logs file

nodemanager log file for 4000 line and still get more

```
2017-06-12 14:22:07,334 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 65.9 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-12 14:22:10,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 65.9 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-12 14:22:13,361 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 65.9 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-12 14:22:16,369 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 65.9 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-12 14:22:19,382 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 66.2 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-12 14:22:22,390 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 66.2 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-12 14:22:25,399 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 66.6 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2017-06-12 14:22:28,409 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 3010 for container-id container_1497203056582_0017_01_000001: 67.1 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 3.3 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
```

resourcemanager log file

```
2017-06-12 13:55:49,493 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for root (auth:TOKEN)
2017-06-12 13:55:49,496 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1497203056582_0017_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2017-06-12 13:58:00,204 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for root (auth:TOKEN)
2017-06-12 13:59:19,231 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Activating next master key with id: -52240461
2017-06-12 13:59:19,292 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTokenSecretManager: Activating next master key with id: -463771108
2017-06-12 13:59:19,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Activating next master key with id: 1973280870
2017-06-12 14:00:01,821 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for root (auth:TOKEN)
2017-06-12 14:00:40,402 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for root (auth:TOKEN)
2017-06-12 14:08:31,967 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for root (auth:TOKEN)
2017-06-12 14:09:08,837 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Creating password for identifier: owner=root, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=root, issueDate=1497290948803, maxDate=1497895748803, sequenceNumber=98, masterKeyId=3, currentKey: 3
2017-06-12 14:09:08,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing RMDelegation token with sequence number: 98
2017-06-12 14:09:37,379 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Creating password for identifier: owner=root, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=root, issueDate=1497290977379, maxDate=1497895777379, sequenceNumber=99, masterKeyId=3, currentKey: 3
2017-06-12 14:09:37,424 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing RMDelegation token with sequence number: 99
2017-06-12 14:20:49,577 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for root (auth:TOKEN)
2017-06-12 14:20:56,681 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Creating password for identifier: owner=root, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=root, issueDate=1497291656681, maxDate=1497896456681, sequenceNumber=100, masterKeyId=3, currentKey: 3
2017-06-12 14:20:56,698 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing RMDelegation token with sequence number: 100
2017-06-12 14:21:17,592 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Creating password for identifier: owner=root, renewer=oozie mr token, realUser=root, issueDate=1497291677592, maxDate=1497896477592, sequenceNumber=101, masterKeyId=3, currentKey: 3
2017-06-12 14:21:17,592 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing RMDelegation token with sequence number: 101
```

Comment: map memory and reduce memory of cluster?

Comment: can you tell me how to see this when run mapreduce by oozie command ?

Comment: i alway see resourcemanager and nodemanager log file

Comment: are you using cloudera distribution or any other?

Comment: i see the problem it going heart beat error stuck in 95% mapreduce if i kill the application oozie pig job go fine . 
Do you have any solution to fix that heart beat ?